# Swiper slider only working when window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm trying to display a horizontal timeline that can be scrolled. At the moment, I'm able to scroll the timeline only when I resize the window page, I don't know why this is happening, I think all my code is right I want the timeline to be scrolled without having the need to resize the window. Is there a fix to this issue? Below is my code for the swiper.

```
<!--JAVASCRIPT CODE.-->
<
script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0" > < /script> <
  script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.min.js"
integrity = "sha256-4sETKhh3aSyi6NRiA+qunPaTawqSMDQca/xLWu27Hg4="
crossorigin = "anonymous" > < /script> <
  script >
  const data = [];

function dataFunction(dataTimeLine) {
  for (var key in dataTimeLine) {
    var value = dataTimeLine[key];
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      data.push({
        dateLabel: key,
        title: value[i]
      });
    }
  }
}


// For the timeline funtionality
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    steps: data
  },
  mounted() {

    var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".next-slide",
        prevEl: ".prev-slide"
      }
    });
  }
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to trigger an update programmatically:

```
 var swiper = new Swiper(/* [...] */);
 swiper.update();
```

This might have the same effect as the resize has.